# How to handle Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am just wondering if someone could help me with the following. I am using VB. NET and SQL Server and want to include some error handling in my code.

I am doing a SQL SUM command which returns fine with no problems providing there is a match in the database. But when there is no match to the String I have specified I get a "Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid."

I understand this error occurs because I have no value in the database to which I have specified.

Below is the code that I am using which contains no error handling:

```
Dim dbCount1 As Integer
    SQLConnectLog()
    strSQLog = "SELECT SUM ([TotalTime]) FROM [Line1Log] WHERE ([State] = 'Test')"
    dbCommandLog = New SqlCommand(strSQLog, dbConnectionLog)
    dbCount1 = dbCommandLog.ExecuteScalar()
    SQLDisconnectLog()
    lblTest.Text = dbCount1
```

Now I have tried several different ways to use isDBNull but to no avail, such as:

```
Dim dbCount1 As Integer
    SQLConnectLog()
    strSQLog = "SELECT SUM ([TotalTime]) FROM [Line1Log] WHERE ([State] = 'Test')"
    dbCommandLog = New SqlCommand(strSQLog, dbConnectionLog)
    If IsDBNull(dbCount1 = dbCommandLog.ExecuteScalar()) Then
        SQLDisconnectLog()
        lblTest.Text = dbCount1
    Else
        lblTest.Text = "0"
    End If
```

The method I used above still does not work.

I am sure I need to use isDBNull function but no sure where to place it.

If anyone could give me some insight on how this can be done I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pure SQL solution can rely in coalesce or isnull for this simple query just returning a single aggregate column.

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM ([TotalTime]), 0) FROM [Line1Log] WHERE ([State] = 'Test')
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for this response, this is my chosen answer as it works perfectly, exactly what I wanted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Try to change dbCount1 to nullable integer

```
Dim dbCount1 As Nullable(Of Integer)
```

Or

```
Dim dbCount1 As Integer?
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it helped me out a great deal

Answer (score 1):

Define dbCount1 as a [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx) integer and call `dbCount.HasValue` to check whether the value is a Null or a valid integer:

```
....
Dim dbCount1 as Integer? = dbCommandLog.ExecuteScalar()
if (dbCount1.HasValue) Then
    lblTest.Text = dbCount1
...
```

An even better option is to use the [If](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) operator, to return a default value if the first argument is null:

```
Dim dbCount1 as Integer? = dbCommandLog.ExecuteScalar()
lblTest.Text=If(dbCount1,0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I have tried the two examples that you have given me and the method makes a lot of sense thank you. However when using the examples above I get a "Specified cast is not valid." error.

Comment: With Integer, Nothing will set the value as = 0.  For example: Dim dbCount1 = If(Not IsDBNull(row.Item(3)), CInt(row.Item(3)), Nothing)

Comment: @JoshYates1980 no, the implicit conversion from *Null* (that's what Nothing is) to `int` will - mixing up *actual* 0s with nulls. Such implicit conversions are undesirable as they lead to undetectable bugs

Comment: My comment was related to the question, but untested.  My code that was tested: Public Class Person with Public Property Age As Integer?   This was set to 0:  Person.Age = If(Not IsDBNull(row.Item(3)), CInt(row.Item(3)), Nothing)

Comment: @JoshYates1980 that's worse. `Integer?` means the property should *accept* Nulls. Your code replaces them with 0 instead. That's a *bug*.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I have 25 years of data and building a MVC platform for the dinosaur application with an Oracle backend that has NULLs for Integer datatypes in the database.   I exploring all angles for design but have chosen to use Public Property Age As String and then convert to Integer when manipulating data for Razor.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, my verbiage might have been confusing. I wanted Null., but the conditional statement set it to 0.   Nothing became 0.  So, I'm using String datatype since I can not alter the database syntax and moved over the dataset from the old webforms application.

Answer (score 1):

try below if condition instead of yours,

`If(dbCommandLog.ExecuteScalar() = DBNull.Value, False, True)`

Answer (score 0):

```
dbCount1 =CInt(dbCommandLog.ExecuteScalar())
```

Try this Code

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your response however the above code gives me the same error.